# Translate sybase select to mssql select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

i need to translate some sql select from sybase to mssql dialect. Problems cause me simple queries with aliases.
a simple example

```
select amount * 2 as doubleamount, doubleamount / 4 as half amount from event
```

You can see that the alias names are still used. With such simple ones as here, you can write `amount * 2` several times. With complex queries you can't do that anymore, especially not if procedures etc. I have selects with dozens of alias-colums that are expected to continue. Can I somehow access the already existing result and keep reckoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a derived table?

Setup:

```
drop table if exists event;
create table event(amount money);
insert into event (amount) values (4);
```

If you only need one level of re-use then a single derived table should suffice, eg:

```
select doubleamount,
       doubleamount / 4 as [half amount]
from
        (select amount * 2 as doubleamount
         from   event ) dt;

doubleamount | half amount
------------ | -----------
8.0000       | 2.0000
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9cbc33ba4a6abdff9f4d374347647e9) of the above.

If you need to reference `doubleamount` then you could turn the above into it's own derived table (ie, use nested derived tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias in a follow on column. Instead, you need to use the actual function. Also, column names must be enclosed in [brackets] if they contain spaces, or are a reserved work in SQL Server.

```
select 
   amount * 2 as doubleamount, 
   (amount * 2) / 4 as [half amount]
from event
```

Here is a more unified method of aliasing that many find *better*. I changed the space to an underscore also.

```
select 
   doubleamount = amount * 2, 
   half_amount = (amount * 2) / 4
from event
```